# WordPress pagination links not showing up for custom post type query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to paginate list of custom post types. This list shows okay, but I can't seem to make pagination links to show.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'families',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'paged'=>$paged
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>

    <table class="families">

        <tr>
            <th class="family_head">Family Head</th>
            <th class="address">Address</th>
            <th class="contact_number">Contact number</th>
        </tr>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <tr>

            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>

            <td><?php the_field( 'residence_address' ); ?></td>

            <td class="contact_number"><?php the_field( 'mobile_number_1' ); ?></td>

        </tr>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php else: ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </table>
```

Other similar WP functions for pagination aren't working either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I erased all the code for pagination and re-did it. It works now. See if you can find the change.

Here is the working code -

```
<div id="main_content">

<div id="main_content_otherpages">

    <?php

        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'families',
            'posts_per_page' => 20,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>

    <table class="families">

        <tr>
            <th class="family_head">Family Head</th>
            <th class="address">Address</th>
            <th class="contact_number">Contact number</th>
        </tr>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <tr>

            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>  

            <td><?php the_field( 'residence_address' ); ?></td>

            <td class="contact_number"><?php the_field( 'mobile_number_1' ); ?></td>

        </tr>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </table>

    <div style="clear:none; float:left"><?php next_posts_link( '&larr;Previous', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
    <div style="clear:none; float:right"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next&rarr;' ); ?></div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this line -
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr;Previous', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the problem of **get_query_var('paged')**,Where you are using this code, have checked **$paged**, 
Try to replace this

`$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;`

There is a difference between  page vs. paged.
You can read more [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Hope, this will help. You can ask if may i help you further.Thanks

Comment: The page I am trying to display this on is not a static front page. Even then I tried what you suggested. But it isn't working. :(

Comment: what you get in $paged ??